# jquery find parents of specific inputs and apply class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a selection div with checkboxes inside and I'm trying to style them with bootstrap buttons and jQuery. Each `input checkbox` takes the attribute `"checked"` by php. So what I need is:

- find all the `inputs` which are 'checked', go to their `parent` labels and eventually `addClass active`.

My html (in php foreach loop)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$ss = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."project_email_alerts where uid='$uid'";
$rr = $wpdb->get_results($ss);
$terms = get_terms( 'project_cat', 'parent=0&orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );
foreach($terms as $term):
    $chk = (KleeiaDev_check_list_emails($term->term_id, $rr) == true ? "checked='checked'" : "");?>
    <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
        <label id="b-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="btn btn-default">
            <div class="bizcontent">
                <input id="a-<?php echo $term->term_id ?>" type="checkbox" name="email_cats[]" <?php echo $chk ?> value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"></span>
                <h5><?php echo $term->name ?></h5>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've tried with jQuery at this way, searching on other similar questions without success:

```
if($('input').is(':checked')){
   jQuery(this).parent('label').addClass('active');
}
```

I've tried with some use of .each but not really sure about that.

Comment: try this way `$('input:checkbox:checked').parent().addClass('active');`

Comment: If you know with php that checkbox is checked - maybe you can add class with php already?

Comment: @guradio Thanks very much for your help! that's what I needed

Comment: @XiLab grald it works :) happy coding mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').parents('label').addClass('active');
```

```js
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').parents('label').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label >
    <input type='checkbox' checked='true'> Check me
  <label>
</div>
  
<div>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox'> Check me
  <label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's important to add class on client side, but on server side you can do it too:

```
$chk = (KleeiaDev_check_list_emails($term->term_id, $rr) == true ? "checked='checked'" : "");?>
<label id="b-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="btn btn-default <?=!empty($chk) 'active' : ''?>">
```

Comment: Ehehe Thanks dude! I'm lately so fallen in love for jQuery that I often don't think at the whole picture. Well it's not necessary actually the client side validation. I will accept the other answer because it was specific on this but I'll opt for the php solution. Thanks!